# given the min and max element in the array, how to sort it?

Tags: arrays, algorithm

Given an array A of n integers, find an algorithm that can sort array A in O(n + y − x) time, where x is the minimum integer in A and y is the maximum integer in A. 
so far I can only think of putting the smallest element in A[0] and the largest in A[n], can anyone help?(homework question)

```
#include <stdio.h>
int sort(int array, int x, int y){
    int j = 0;
    int temp = 0;
    for (j<=4){
        if (array[j] == x){
            temp = array[0];
            array[0] = array[j];
            array[j]=temp;
        }
        else if (array[j] == y){
            temp = array[4];
            array[0] = array[j];
            array[j]=temp;
        }
        //////////////////////////////////////////////
        ////////////////////////////////////////////
        ////////////////////////////////////////////
    }
    return 0;
}

int main(){
    int array[5]={3,2,5,4,1};
    sort(array,1,5);
    int i = 0;
    for (i<=4){
        printf("%d\n",array[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What's wrong with what you have?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.  Since you haven't specified a programming problem, we don't have anything to do for you.

Comment: ["Can Someone Help Me?" is not a valid SO question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question).  This usually suggests that what you need is half an hour with a local tutor or walk through a tutorial, rather than Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is indirectly asking you to use counting sort. The concept is simple:

1. Create an array of size y - x with all 0 elements
2. Go through the initial array adding 1 to the index in the new array that corresponds to the value [O(n)]
3. Go through the new array outputting the index as many times as the value stored [O(y - x)]

Example:

- Initial array `[3, 2, 3, 4, 1]`
- New array `[0, 0, 0, 0]`
- Adding 1 to corresponding value `[1, 1, 2, 1]`
- Returning the index as many times as many times as needed `[1, 2, 3, 3, 4]`

Corresponding index in our case means `value - x`

There is also a deeper explanation on wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counting_sort